# refreshing part of page anngularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax, ui-calendar

i have a webpage and i have two controller.One controller is used to get data from the db and update ui-calendar events and another controller to submit form data to the db.I want to refresh my card(Where the first controller is used) with the new inserted value ie as soon as the value is added to the db the view should be updated with the new table data and shown on the ui-calendar.How to do this with angular and js. These are my controllers

```html
app.controller('myNgController', ['$scope', '$http','$rootScope', 'uiCalendarConfig', function ($scope, $http,$rootScope, uiCalendarConfig) {

$calendar = $('[ui-calendar]');

var date = new Date(),
  d = date.getDate(),
  m = date.getMonth(),
  y = date.getFullYear();

$scope.changeView = function(view){      
   $calendar.fullCalendar('changeView',view);
};

/* config object */
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar: {
    lang: 'da',
    height: 450,
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,

    
    header: {
      left: 'month basicWeek basicDay',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    eventClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      $scope.alertMessage = (date.title + ' was clicked ');
      alert("clicked"+date.title);
    },
    select: function(start, end, allDay)
 {
  
     var obj = {};
     obj.startAt = start.toDate();
     
     
     obj.startAt=new Date(obj.startAt).toUTCString();
     obj.startAt=obj.startAt.split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ');
     
     obj.endAt = end.toDate();
     obj.endAt=new Date(obj.endAt).toUTCString();
     obj.endAt=obj.endAt.split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ');
     
     
     
     $rootScope.selectionDate = obj;
     
     
     
     $("#modal1").openModal();
  
  
  calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
 },
   
    eventRender: $scope.eventRender
  }
};

$scope.events=[];
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
$http.get("rest/leave/list", {
    cache: true,
    params: {}
}).then(function (data) {
    $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);
    angular.forEach(data.data, function (value) {
     console.log(value.title);
        $scope.events.push({
         
            title: value.title,
            description: value.description,
            start: value.startAt,
            end: value.endAt,
            allDay : value.isFull,
            stick: true
        });
    });
});

 

app.controller("MyAddController", function($scope, $http,$rootScope) {
 $scope.test = {};
 
    $scope.add = function() {
     $scope.test1=$rootScope.selectionDate;
     var jsonData = JSON.stringify($.extend({}, $scope.test, $scope.test1));
     console.log(""+jsonData);
     
     //console.log("------------>"+JSON.stringify($jsonData));
     $http({
         url: "rest/leave/create",
         method: "POST",
         data: jsonData,
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                alert("success");
            }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error");
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I would suggest using `$broadcast`. Once your DB is updated (in the `.success` callback function), broadcast an event on `$rootScope`. You can then listen to this event in your other controller and do whatever you need to do after the event is received.

Add to `MyAddController`:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('MyAddController.success');
```

Add to your `MyDbController`:

```
const removeRootScopeListener = $rootScope.$on('MyAddController.success', () => {
    // Do whatever you need to do here
});
```

Do not forget, that event listeners on `$rootScope` are not cleaned up automatically, when your local `$scope` is destroyed. To prevent a memory leak, remove the event listener manually.

To remove the event listener:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
    removeRootScopeListener();
});
```

Comment: really sorry for the confusion,edited my question with updated controller.I am not understanding which function to call inside $rootScope.$on('MyAddController.success' so that my view gets updated.Please help.Thank you

Comment: Call a function which gets data from the database and saves that data on `$scope`. I am not sure which one, as the one doing that was part of the `MyDbController` and I cannot find that in your code anymore.

Comment: yes sorry for that .I added that controller in a hurry.This is my actual controller .This controller is used to display and update the events of ui-calendar.But i am not understanding which function of this controller to call in the $rootScope.$on('MyAddController.success'.....any clue?

Comment: I am not sure, your code is very confusing. I think the block starting with `$http.get("rest/leave/list", ...`. That is the one which seems to be fetching data from the server and exposing them to the view.

Comment: nope..whatever i tried the changes werent reflecting in the calendar